# Converting Tkinter app withoul CLI

Tags: py2exe, cx-freeze

So I've created a tkinter program and saved it as a .pyw file so that when I run it it will not show the CLI backgound window but when I compiled it using py2exe and cx-Freeze and run the executable it showed the CLI prompt. How will I be able to compile it into an executable file that when run it won't show the black window?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can hide the CLI using:

```
base = Win32GUI
```

For example in this script:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": []}
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base)])
```

---

EDIT:

You mention media files not being included.  This is quite normal you have to specify those manually.  Although there are many ways you can do this the easiest way is to use `include_files` argument.  This is fairly simple and can be done like this:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": [], "include_files":["Path/To/Media/Files.jpg"]}
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "guifoo",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("guifoo.py", base=base)])
```

Using this method you can include whole folders like this:

```
"include_files":["path/to/folder"]
```

or individual files (As shown above) like this:

```
"include_files":["path/to/file.png"]
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. It actually worked but something was wrong. The build was successful but all the media files were not copied so I have to move it manually. By the way, what if I want to use py2exe instead of cx_Freeze, would you be able to help me?

Comment: @LeeYou No sorry I don't know py2exe (also it only works for python 2) also what are the names and file paths of the media files to include?  I'll edit to include these once you tell me.

Comment: Thanks for the help Simon.